# Can I complete the ending without a straight tower?

Tags: stephens-sausage-roll

I completed the last level before the ending in Stephen's Sausage Roll without making the tower completely straight, but still with a ladder all the way up.
[image]
But now a can't get the sausage at the top down. I can see how to do it with 2 ladders, but not like this. The problem is I quit the game after that level, and now I can't undo to change the tower.

Is there a way to complete this, or is it impossible to complete the game now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer here. If you're convinced you can't progress, from the escape menu you can load older versions of your game.  (It's a long level to re-solve, I admit...)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know you could load a previous save, but I redid the level and manages to complete it now.